# Pushing commits to gitlab LFS using the https API

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs, gitlab-api

I was wondering if there is a method in Gitlab's REST or GraphQL API (Gitlab Community Edition 15.11.2) to commit images while saving them in the LFS (Large File Storage). I'm aware that there is an endpoint

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/repository/commits
```

that can be used to to commit files, but it doesn't seem to support the automatic saving of the files that are being commited to LFS. Unfortunately, it appears that any interaction with gitlab's LFS is meant to be conducted via CLI.

Some solutions suggest calling a request to the

```
/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/lfs/objects
```

endpoint to upload the file first, and then using OID and LFS pointer retrieved from the response to call the aforementioned /repository/commits endpoint. However, It doesn't seem to work either.

My only goal here is to save the files I commit with REST or GraphQL API in the LFS storage. I'm considering any other ways to achieve that, including the use of gitlab's CI pipeline, cron scripts or any other means I may not be aware of.